# Why is the output of nested loops in a different order than expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

This is a program to print each letter of a string along with cordinates of the letter in the matrix.

In this example, the output should be

```
['s12', 'k12', 'i33', 'l13', 'l13', 'r11', 'a11', 'c13', 'k12']
```

But I actually get

```
['r11', 'a11', 's12', 'k12', 'k12', 'l13', 'l13', 'c13', 'i33']
```

```
s1 = "skillrack"
mat1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
mat2 = [['j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', '.', 'n'], ['o', 'p', 'q']]
mat3 = [['r', 's', 't'], ['u', 'v', 'w'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
ans = []

for i in range(0, len(mat1)):
  for j in range(0, len(mat1[i])):
    for x in range(0, len(s1)):
      
      if s1[x] == mat1[i][j]:
        ans.append(str(s1[x]) + str(i+1) + str(j+1))
        
      elif s1[x] == mat2[i][j]:
        ans.append(str(s1[x]) + str(i+1) + str(j+1))
        
      elif s1[x] == mat3[i][j]:
        print(mat3[i][j])
        ans.append(str(s1[x]) + str(i+1) + str(j+1))  
       
print(ans)
```

The output of `ans` is shuffled, I need it in the order of `s1`. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: By the way: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The outermost loop defines the order in which the items appear in the list.

If you want the list to be in the same order as the input string `s1`, then the loop `for x in range(0, len(s1)):` must come first:

```
for x in range(0, len(s1)):
  for i in range(0, len(mat1)):
    for j in range(0, len(mat1[i])):
```

Comment: Not a requirement but your code will look better if you follow [PEP8, Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations. Also, `range()` `start` already defaults to `0`, so there is no need to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, I did not change anything else to make it clear that the order of the loops is what matters here. I did not want to overload the answer with a code review.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the order you could loop over each character in `s1` and get the correct value. This differs from your original approach.

```
def get_code(needle, matrixes):
    for matrix in matrixes:
        for index1, characters in enumerate(matrix, start=1):
            for index2, character in enumerate(characters, start=1):
                if needle == character:
                    return f'{needle}{index1}{index2}'

result = [get_code(character, [mat1, mat2, mat3]) for character in s1]
print(result)
```

This will give you `['s12', 'k12', 'i33', 'l13', 'l13', 'r11', 'a11', 'c13', 'k12']`.

I used a list comprehension to loop over the character of the string and delegated the task of finding the correct value to the function `get_code`. Since using `range` for an index access is considered *unpythonic*  I used `enumerate` to get the index and the matching value.

Answer (score 0):

[`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) objects in Python can be indexed and used as arrays.

[`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) `start` value already defaults to `0`, so there is no need to pass it as the first argument to `range()`.

[`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) are a better option than converting numbers into strings and then concatenating them all together.

Not a requirement but your code will look better if you follow [PEP8, Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommendations.

With the above concepts in mind, here is a more *Pythonic* version of your code, with the fix suggested by @mkrieger1 in his answer:

```py
s1 = 'skillrack'
m1 = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
m2 = ['jkl', 'm.n', 'opq']
m3 = ['rst', 'uvw', 'xyz']
ans = []

for c in s1:
    for i, m1i in enumerate(m1):
        for j, m1ij in enumerate(m1i):
            if c == m1ij:
                ans.append(f'{c}{i + 1}{j + 1}')
            elif c == m2[i][j]:
                ans.append(f'{c}{i + 1}{j + 1}')
            elif c == m3[i][j]:
                ans.append(f'{c}{i + 1}{j + 1}')
print(ans)
```

The code above will give you the following output:

```py
['s12', 'k12', 'i33', 'l13', 'l13', 'r11', 'a11', 'c13', 'k12']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1="skillrack"
mat1=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
mat2=[['j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', '.', 'n'], ['o', 'p', 'q']]
mat3=[['r', 's', 't'], ['u', 'v', 'w'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
ans=[]
for i in range(len(s1)):
   for j in range(len(mat1)):
       for k in range(len(mat1)):
        if s1[i]==mat1[j][k]:
             ans.append(s1[i]+str(j+1)+str(k+1))
        elif s1[i]==mat2[j][k]:
            ans.append(s1[i]+str(j+1)+str(k+1))
        elif s1[i]==mat3[j][k]:
            ans.append(s1[i]+str(j+1)+str(k+1))
            
print(ans)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use list comprehension to get a sorted list for your answer like:

```
print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: int("".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()]))))
```

or

```
print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: int("".join([i for i in x if i.isalpha()]))))
```

Comment: OP wants it in order of chars in the string, not sorted list

Comment: They do not *have* to use a list comprehension. Normal `for` loops are fine.

Comment: Yes, it can be a normal loop also. it will sort both char also as well as numbers.

Comment: Yes broo i need to know why it is shuffling and how to fix it?

Comment: @SarimSikander Bro I need not to sort that "ans" I need to arrange in the manner of s1.